# Foreign key constraint Cascading or multiple cascade paths error asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I always have the same problem, when there is an double inheritance that is:

```
  public class Restriction 
  {
 public int RestrictionID {get;set;}
 public string Restriction_Name {get;set}
 public int AssetID { get; set;}
 public int SegmentID {get;set;}
 public virtual Asset {get;set;}
 public virtual Segment { get;set;}
 }

 public class Asset
{
     [Key]
     public int AssetID
     public string Asset_Name
     public virtual ICollection<Segment> Segments
}
  public class Segment
{
    [Key]
    public int SegmentID
    public string Segment_Name
    [ForeignKey("Asset")]
    public int AssetID
    public virtual Asset Asset
    public virtual ICollection<SubAsset> SubAssets
}
```

I tried to stop the cascading but I get again the same error:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restriction>()
                .HasRequired(f => f.Segment)
                .WithRequiredDependent()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Can somebody help me with that ? I am going crazy with this issue!

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't mix and match attributes and fluent api mappings, pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @BenRobinson how do will you do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Restriction, Asset and Segment classes, all foreign keys are required.

```
public class Asset
{
    ...    
    // Restrictions is missing
    public virtual ICollection<Restriction> Restrictions { get; set; }
}
```

### Mapping

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Restrictions)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Asset)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Segments)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Asset)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Segment>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Restrictions)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Segment)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: hello do I have to add the property ICollection<Restriction> Restrictions in the Asset Class even if I don't want to write on the table Assets it is just a table that gives me informations